# Not able to get MongoDB.driver nuget for Webapi project

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am new to MongoDB and is trying to get this new Database connected with my Web api application ..But i am not able to add MongoDB.driver nuget for my Webapi project.Please refer screen shot.
[image]
My search is struck on this window for like forever.,have even restarted my project for a couple of times now.

I also tried installing [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/) package through

```
PM>Install-Package MongoDB.Driver
```

But then this is shown[image]

Am I doing something wrong ..?

Comment: Do you have proxy configured on your machine? Or "http_proxy" variable configured in environment variable? And could you try access the url "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" from browser to check whether it can be accessed from browser directly?

Comment: Dont know about any environment variable thing but i tried opening this url"https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"...but it says this site cant be reached..what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

> i tried opening this url"api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"...but it says this site cant be reached..what does that mean?

Since the you could not open the url in browser directly, there should be some internet limitations in your internet environment. If you are work in the company, I suggest you contact your office IT to confirm whether they add any limitations and whether used any proxy. If they are using some proxy, you need to set the proxy settings in NuGet.Config file which store in C:\Users\user name\AppData\Roaming\NuGet as below settings. Detailed information please refer to the Proxy settings part in [Nuget Config Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file#config-section) & [Nuget Proxy Settings](http://skolima.blogspot.sg/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html).

```
<add key="http_proxy" value="host" />
<add key="http_proxy.user" value="username" />
<add key="http_proxy.password" value="encrypted_password" />
```

Besides, you can chech the proxy in your machine: Open "System Properties" > Advanced > Environment Variables. Find the http_proxy var (in System variables), select and delete it.